# Android Create Drawable Image With Code

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

**I need to be able to create a custom image through code, and then set that image to an imageview**

I want this image to have a solid background colour, a title and an icon.
I want it to be customisable so that I can call to create an image with values
for example

```
createImage(String bckgColourHex, String title, int iconResource){
 // create image using value here

return image.
}
```

Then I can use the drawable to set it to my imageView

**This is what I am trying so far**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        BitmapDrawable customImage = writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.background_gradient, "TEXT GOES HERE");
        image.setBackgroundDrawable(customImage);

    }


    public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        paint.setTextSize(20); 

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

        return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static Drawable makeBorderedDrawable(Context mContext, int width, String xCode, Boolean unAvail) {

    Paint p = new Paint();
    Bitmap bkg = null;
    final int FULL_ALPHA = 0xFF123456; // of whatever color you want

    int pixel = FULL_ALPHA;

    // first create a mutable bitmap
    bkg = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bkg);

    p.setColor(pixel);
    c.drawCircle(width / 2, width / 2, width / 2, p);

    // or draw rect, or lines, or drawtext....or whatever


    return new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bkg);

    // or you could return a Bitmap if you prefer.

}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain what the xcode and Boolean are for. thanks

Comment: Got it working, thank you for pointing my in the right direction :)

Comment: xCode was simple a hex value for RGB.  The boolean I used to draw different aspects based on business logic. Sorry I wasn't more clear